# possible to have a two-password login for a linux user (specifically root)

Tags: linux, passwords

Is it possible to have a linux login system for a user that requires two passwords?  One after the other, ideally not necessarily in any order.

The purpose of this is to require two separate users to sign off of the access.  Each would know only one password.

Comment: This is typically done by requiring a user without superuser permissions, to run commands as root (or another superuser account) which has a different password then their account.

Comment: I don't believe that will work as the super user account is greater than the user account.  I want two people to have co-equal access, but they both must enter their password.  Sort of like some bank checks require two signatures.  A login to the system always means that two people were present.

Comment: @Ramhound actually, you can quite easily set it up with sudo, it's just a pain to do so. You need to create a second user db, store the hashed passwords in this, and setup the pam module to authenicate against this.

So user1 would have user2's password in the db. Sudo would request a password (being user2's) and authenticate them.

Comment: @OliverWillaims: I misunderstood your question completely and deleted my answer. Sorry for any inconveniences:-)